# Angular 2 Firebase Return Object Count

Tags: angular, date, firebase, time, angularfire

I am working in Angular 2 and have a booking component.

When a booking is made, the information is sent to firebase database in a bookings node.

I am trying to show on the home screen dashboard of the app if the admin has any bookings today. in my component I have subscribed to the bookings node in firebase using Angularfire as follows:

```
this.bookingItemsData = af.database.list('/bookings');
this.bookingItemsData.subscribe((res) => {
  this.bookingItems = res;
  console.log(res);
```

I want to get the current date and compare it to the date give in firebase bookings node, so to get current date I have added this:

```
//get current date
    var getToday = new Date();
    var year = getToday.getFullYear();
    var month = getToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = getToday.getDate();
    // var time =  getToday.getTime();
    var currentDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

Which successfully gets me the currentDate I require.

I now run this to get the dates from the bookings:

```
// Get count of bookings
    af.database.list('/bookings').subscribe((res) => {
        this.numbeOfBookings = res.length;
        res.forEach(item => {
        //get the date propery from the bookings node  
        var specialDate = (item.start);
        //transform the date property to matching format
        specialDate = this.datePipeEn.transform(new Date(item.start), 'dd/M/yyyy');

        // console.log(specialDate);
        // console.log(currentDate);

          if(specialDate === currentDate) {
          console.log(specialDate);
          } 

        });
    });
```

I first get the number of bookings in the booking list,

I then iterate through the bookings and assign the booking date to a variable 'specialDate' using a ForEach Statement

I then run the variable through the datePipe to match the booking date output to the required format,

I then run an if statement to see if any of my returned dates match the current date.

---

When I console.log my specialDate I am getting the one date returned out of the 2 that match todays date which is great.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXir5.png)

but when I do console.log(specialDate.length)

it counts the characters in the date instead of returning '1' (the amount of matching booking dates to the current date.

So I guess what I am returning is a string and its counting that instead of returning an object. how would I get the count of the objects with matching dates to the currentDate?

---

UPDATE:

I managed to return the only bookings that match the current date as an object using the following code:

```
// Get count of bookings
af.database.list('/bookings').subscribe((res) => {
    this.numbeOfBookings = res.length;
    res.forEach(item => {
    //get the date propery from the bookings node  
    var specialDate = (item.start);
    //transform the date property to matching format
    specialDate = this.datePipeEn.transform(new Date(item.start), 'dd/M/yyyy');

      if(specialDate === currentDate) {
        console.log(item);
      } 

    });
});
```

On the console log I see the only object which is a booking that matches todays date.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B391o.png)

However, if I do this: console.log(item.length); it counts the keys in the object and not return the number '1' I was hoping for. (the amount of bookings that match todays date)

How would I return the number 1, for the 1 object that was returned?

---

UPDATE

I managed to get the count of objects returned which is 1 :)

here is what I did, I had to make each item an object, then put the returned objects into an array then I could successfully console.log the returned value i was after! :)

```
 // Get count of bookings
this.test = af.database.list('/bookings').subscribe((res) => {
    this.numbeOfBookings = res.length;

    res.forEach(item => {      
      var bookingDate = (item.start); //get the date propery from the bookings node        
      bookingDate = this.datePipeEn.transform(new Date(item.start), 'dd/M/yyyy'); //transform the date property to matching format
      var myObj = {item}; // Put each returned item into an object
      var array = $.map(myObj, function (value, index) { // Create an array with the returned objects
        return [value];
      });

      if(bookingDate === currentDate) {

        var bookingsToday = array
        var bookingsCount = array.length
        // console.log(bookingsToday);
        return(bookingsCount);

      } 

    });
});
```

I do have one final question however.

How would I use {{interpolation}} to reference this returned 'bookingsCount' value in my html template? (Angular 2) Many thanks in advance.

---

> > Continuation of comments on first answer <<

[new screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXir5.png)

Here is the screenshot of the console when I added console.log(specialDate,currentDate);

here is the code:

```
af.database.list('/bookings').subscribe((res) => {
    var i = 0 
    this.numbeOfBookings = res.length;
    res.forEach(item => {
        var specialDate = (item.start);
        specialDate = this.datePipeEn.transform(new Date(item.start),'dd/M/yyyy');
        console.log(specialDate,currentDate);
          if(specialDate === currentDate) {
            i++ 
            console.log(item)
          } 

        });
    //use you variable here
    console.log(i)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to increment a variable in you if statement, and after forEach you can use your variable :

```
af.database.list('/bookings').subscribe((res) => {
var i = 0 <----------- init a variable
this.numbeOfBookings = res.length;
res.forEach(item => {
    var specialDate = (item.start);
    specialDate = this.datePipeEn.transform(new Date(item.start),'dd/M/yyyy');
      console.log(specialDate,currentDate); <-----------
      if(specialDate === currentDate) {
        i++ <-------------- increment it each time the date is the same
        console.log(item);
      } 

    });
//use you variable here
console.log(i)
});
```

i advice you :

1. to use, angularfire (official angular 2 firebase) you can find it in github,
2. if you work with angularfire, so try the queries, and get the list of your matching dates from the server
3. the ultimate advice is to quit firebase if you don't need realtime feature, even so, try AWS dynamo with lambda, or get you hand dirty using socket.io and Mlab(Free mongodb as service)